# IMDb dataset find number of 10 ratings for a movie

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

I'm trying to sort IMDb movies based on the number of (rated 10) votes they got.
 Unfortunately, I can't seem to find that piece of information in their public dataset on their FTP servers (It's not in the ratings file).
Example of the information I'm trying to extract:
[The Shawshank Redemption](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/ratings?ref_=tt_ov_rt) has 955769 votes of a 10 rating.
Is there any other way this could be done?
Can IMDbPy help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the rating information by using the IMDbPY package.

Follow the steps as shown in the link [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/support.html#documentation).

You can actually do it in two ways,

1. Use the **api** provided which is a straight forward method (works in cases where the number of api calls are less).
2. But in case you have multiple api calls, you need to create a **local IMDb database**. You can do it by running the python script provided by IMDbPY which automatically creates tables for you in the database (follow the steps as mentioned [here](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/docs/README.sqldb.txt)).

Other way of doing it (not recommended) is by creating a web scraper which is a painful process. Can build one with the help of *requests*, *beautifulsoup* packages in python.

Comment: Thank you. I've figured out a way to get the rough number of 10 ratings from the file somehow (a percentage of the votes), I just need to calculate them for each movie, and put them in a new column to sort. I'll try doing that with IMDbPY.